# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am creating a DrawerNavigation with react-navigation . Everything was working fine in a single file until I decided to split it into smaller modules . 
The structure is basic Drawer Navigator which contains a couple of Stack Navigators inside.

```
DrawerNavigators.js
StackNavigators
        |__HomeNavigator.js
        |__MenuNavigator.js
```

I spent hours trying to investigate the issue, and at first the error seemed to be related to modules not properly being imported but now I reckon my imports are kind of right but I still get the error as soon as I try to navigate to a particular screen .

Here is my code sample :

> DrawerNavigator.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Platform, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import HomeNavigator from './StackNavigators/HomeNavigator';
import {   
    createStackNavigator, 
    createAppContainer, 
    createDrawerNavigator,
        } from 'react-navigation';

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Acceuil: {
        screen: HomeNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Acceuil',
            drawerLabel: 'Acceuil',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon 
                    name='home'
                    type='font-awesome'
                    size={24}
                    color={tintColor}
                    />
            )
        }
    },
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

> HomeNavigator.js

```
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import HomeScreen from '../../HomeComponent';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: "#fff"            
            },
        }
    }
);

export default HomeNavigator;
```

A screenshot to the error can be find below . Any Help would be very appreciated .

[image]

Comment: can you share the changes you made ?

Comment: It was the same code inside a single part . Apart from the import statements in the above files , I haven't changed anything.

Comment: it's the `imports` causing this issue could you put them back and compare again

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I litterally don't know what's going on with my import but as soon as I put it all back in the same file , everything works. I just don't like the idea of having a long and bulky file having the same redundant code .

Comment: Sounds like you may have a dependency cycle causing one of the components to have not been evaluated yet when it is referenced?

Comment: Are you importing and exporting HomeScreen correctly?